# CSS - Drop down menu appearing outside UL

Tags: css, html, drop-down-menu, nav

I am creating a drop down menu using CSS. However when I select the menu it selects in the space that the List will appear and from the UL. Not just the UL if that makes sense and i cannot work out why it does that. Please see the code for the example:-

The CSS:-

```
#navigation .menu ul {position:absolute; top:45px; left:0px; opacity:0; background:black; transition:opacity .25s ease; -webkit-transition:opacity .25s ease;}
#navigation .menu li:hover > ul {opacity:1; margin:0;}
#navigation .menu ul li {height:25px; width:200px; overflow:hidden; border-bottom:red 1px solid; border-left:none; margin:none; transition:opacity .25s ease; -webkit-transition:height .25s ease;}
#navigation .menu ul li:hover {overflow:hidden; margin:0;}
#navigation .menu ul li a {text-decoration:none; height:25px; width:200px;}
#navigation .menu ul li:last-child {border-bottom:none;}
```

HTML code:-

```
<div id="navigation"> <nav> <ul class="menu"> 

        <li> <a href="Option.html"> <h1> Homepage </h1> </a> </li>

        <li> <a href="Option2.html"> About </a> <ul class="ulbox">

                <li class="dm"> <a href="Option1.html"> <img src="images/Avengers.jpeg" width="25" /> The Site </a></li>
                <li class="dm"> <a href="Option2.html"> <img src="images/Doctor Strange.jpeg" width="25" /> Find Us </a></li>
                <li class="dm"> <a href="Option3.html"> <img src="images/Guardians.jpeg" width="25" /> The Company </a></li>
                <li class="dm"> <a href="Option4.html"> <img src="images/Inhumans.jpeg" width="25" /> Contrived Page </a></li>
                <li class="dm"> <a href="Option5.html"> <img src="images/Thor.jpeg" width="25" /> Drop Down Success </a></li>

</ul>  </li>
        <li> <a href="Option3.html"> Images </a> <ul>

                <li> <a href="Option1.html"> The Site </a></li>
                <li> <a href="Option2.html"> Find Us </a></li>
                <li> <a href="Option3.html"> The Company </a></li>
                <li> <a href="Option4.html"> Contrived Page </a></li>
                <li> <a href="Option5.html"> Drop Down Success </a></li>

 </ul> </li> 
            <li> <a href="Option4.html"> The next page </a> <ul>

                <li> <a href="Option1.html"> The Site </a></li>
                <li> <a href="Option2.html"> Find Us </a></li>
                <li> <a href="Option3.html"> The Company </a></li>
                <li> <a href="Option4.html"> Contrived Page </a></li>
                <li> <a href="Option5.html"> Drop Down Success </a></li>

 </ul> </li>
            <li> <a href="Option5.html"> Terms and Stuff  </a> <ul>

                <li> <a href="Option1.html"> The Site </a></li>
                <li> <a href="Option2.html"> Find Us </a></li>
                <li> <a href="Option3.html"> The Company </a></li>
                <li> <a href="Option4.html"> Contrived Page </a></li>
                <li> <a href="Option5.html"> Drop Down Success </a></li>

 </ul> </li> </ul> </nav> </div>
```

I can't see why the menu is showing from outside the UL nav bar. Can someone help?

Comment: Your question is not clear, plz add some more detail or make jsfiddle

Comment: Not sure if I got your question. Looking at the code you are giving `position:absolute` to `ul` under `.menu` so make sure it's parent li has `position:relative`

Comment: Thanks for the response anpsmn. Will give that a go. To explain my issue, basically, although the menu drops down, it does so when not hovering over main nav bar. It can do it when the mouse is quite far away from the nav bar I created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're several things that is wrong with the CSS.

- First: The `position: absolute` will remove the element out of the flow. So won't be counted as something existing to calulate the position of sibling and parent elements.
- Second: Your expecting display still using the `sub Menu` flow. In order to make another `parent Menu` to flow down. So you must not use `position: absolute`. By removing it you will get back the flow of your Menu. (the `position: relative;` is not necessary I just left it there because lazy removing it)
- Third: Now you encounted with the `sub Menu` being displaying without hovering. To deal with it there is 2 ways. But my jsfiddle only use one. Just add `display: none` to the `sub Menu`. And then `display: block` when its parent is hovering. (1)

```css
#navigation .menu ul {
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
  position:relative; 
}
#navigation .menu li:hover > ul {opacity:1; margin:0; display: block}
```

(2)

***NOTE:***

(1): If you want it to look nice with animation. Use the `max-heigth: 0` property as `transition`. (instead of using `display: none;`

(2): `z-index` and `position:relative;`  is not necessary. Just that you need to remove `position: absolute` then it will work

http://jsfiddle.net/7r7zLuar/3/

Comment: Hi. Unfortunately this did not fix the issue. Any other ideas?

Comment: #navigation {width:auto; height:37px; padding: 0 0 10px 0; background:black;}
#navigation ul {width:auto; padding:1px; margin: 0px;}
#navigation li {position:relative; float:left; padding:10px 5px 1px 5px; list-style-type:none; border-left: 1px red solid;}
#navigation li a {text-decoration:none; color:red; display:block;}
#navigation li:first-child {font-family:Helvetica; border-left:none; padding:5px;}
#navigation li:last-child {border-right:none;}

Comment: The drop down menu is appearing in the area where it should appear when i hover the main UL nav bar

Comment: @RMitchell there are many things so wrong within your code. Everything styled badly. And so far I just fix some that they have cause the error. Also what you want that is the design. You will need either a draw of something, because your words so unclear. I will make another jsfiddle from what I guess you meaning.

Comment: Thanks so much for the info, seems to have cured the issue. With the actual style and wording, I am just practising and learning how to use HTML and CSS at the moment. The reason it doesn't look great. What was the core issue if I may ask?

Comment: Wasn't explain because I am not sure if the solution is what you want. I will update the answer really soon. Check it out in like next 10 mins

Comment: Thanks. I wait for the response. But I can tell you now, that has done what I needed

Comment: Seen your new response. Appreciate it. Thanks for the help

Comment: you are welcome, next time if you spend bit more time on making your question. You will get the answer faster. The more it clear the easier the others can help you with, Cheers!   :)